Xiaomi 13T Pro Android Studio Mirroring Bad Screen Quality
As you can see in the picture below, when I try to mirror the Xiaomi 13T Pro device via Android Studio, the shared screen looks pretty bad.
When I use Pair Devices Using Wifi and direct screen mirroring via cable, there is a bad image like this. When I try a different device with the same cable, I see the proper screen quality.
I tried completely resetting the phone (wipe data) but it didn't work.
I tried on both Windows and macOS devices, the image is bad quality.
If anyone who has experienced the problem or knows a solution can help, I would be glad.

I tried completely resetting the phone (wipe data) but it didn't work.
I tried on both Windows and macOS devices, the image is bad quality.
If anyone who has experienced the problem or knows a solution can help, I would be glad.
